# How to debug MongoDB queries for performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a small app and I use MongoDb (Mongoid). The collection is relatively small (about 300 records), however the query is taking a long time (approximately 12s). Here's my query:

```
query = Lead.order(:post_date.desc).cache
query = query.page(params['page_number']).cache if params['page_number']
query = query.per(params['page_size']).cache if params['page_size']
query = query.where(read: params['read']).cache if params['read']
query = query.where(important: @user.id.to_s).cache if params['important'] == "true"
query = query.where(starred: @user.id.to_s).cache if params['starred'] == "true"
```

And I have the fowling indexing setup on the Model:

```
index({ post_date: 1 }, { background: true })
index({ read: 1 }, { background: true })
index({ important: 1 }, { background: true })
index({ starred: 1 }, { background: true })
```

So my question is, 1) how can I improve the performance of this query and 2) is there a tool (like NewRelic although NewRelic doesn't provide details on how improve performance for queries) or service that can monitor the queries and suggest improvements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CloudManager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager/) is a paid-for GUI which provides (amongst others) performance analysis "like NewRelic".

A [built-in profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) logs slow queries (> 100ms) by default, but can be turned on (with caution) to log everything.

An [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to analyse performance of a particular query.

[Compas](https://www.mongodb.com/products/lp/compass) is an official GUI with some performance insights.

More monitoring tools: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/